# An identity about Probability of unions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},P)$ be a probability space and events $A_1,...,A_n \in\mathfrak{A}$ with $P(A_{i_1} \cap...\cap A_{i_k})=P(A_1 \cap...\cap A_k)$ for all $k \in \{1,...,n \},i_k\in\{1,...,n \}$ alongside $i_1<...<i_k$. Show that:
> $$P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k \bigg)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\begin {pmatrix} n\\k \end {pmatrix} P(A_1 \cap ...\cap A_k).$$

I got stuck at some part of this question and would appreciate some help. Firstly its pretty obvious that by the inclusion-exclusion principle we have:
$$P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k \bigg)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1} \cap...\cap A_{i_k})$$
Then by the given property of the probability space we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1} \cap...\cap A_{i_k})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}P(A_1 \cap...\cap A_k).$$
This is where I'm stuck. I'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is. At first I thought it had to do with stochastic independence or something but after looking at it more I simply don't know where the binomial coefficients come from and why the power of -1 changes in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,
$$
\sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1} \cap...\cap A_{i_k})
=\sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}P(A_{1} \cap...\cap A_{k})=P(A_{1} \cap...\cap A_{k})\sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}1
$$
and $\sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}1=\binom nk$.